# Issue with rubygems.rb when installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm

I recently had to delete all my versions in Ruby and reinstall them. After doing so (I'm now using 2.0.0 if that's relevant) I cannot reinstall rails. This was all done with RVM.

Here is the error
    :1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

Update: I tried reinstalling RVM, as Albert suggested. I still receive the same error message.

when I run `which -a ruby`

```
/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

when I run `rvm remove 2.0.0`

```
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/bob/.rvm/log/1389478324_ruby-2.0.0-
p353/remove.rubies.logrm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/tc_timezone_offset_info.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/tc_timezone_period.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/tc_timezone_proxy.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/tc_timezone_transition_info.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/tc_timezone_utc.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/test_utils.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test/ts_all.rb: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/test: Permission denied
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353: Directory not empty
```

Comment: Did you try deleting your .rvm directory and reinstalling it?

Comment: You can reinstall rvm for your user by running `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: @Albert I tried `rvm remove 2.0.0` instead of just `rvm uninstall 2.0.0`. Would I still have to try deleting it and reinstalling rvm itself?

Comment: How did you install rvm in the first place? Via a package manager?

Comment: I believe I used the command you gave when I first installed RVM. But the reinstall does not work, `gem install rails` gives the same error.

Comment: can you paste output of `which -a ruby`?

Comment: Try to run `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` before issuing `gem install rails`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either.

Comment: Are `gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'` and `ruby -v` pointing to rvm's version?

Comment: `gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'` points to the error message, and `ruby -v` points to the correct rvm version

Comment: Dod you install rvm as root, didn't you?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I check that?

Comment: Maybe just check who owns `.rvm`? Or `rvm implode` and install it again. Or `sudo chown -R bob .rvm`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45026/discussion-between-user1796994-and-zrl3dx)

Comment: @user1796994 also, please show output of `ruby -v`, and `which ruby`, before and after the rvm session is initialized.

Answer (score 13):

It is a problem because of using `sudo` (you should not run `sudo`), to fix it run:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

you should be now able to:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

it will reinstall your ruby, ensure everything is set up properly and that your gems are usable with then new ruby.